# .replace method doesn't work in Python even if assigned to a new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I have read some posts before and tried to fix this myself but all of them mentioned that the .replace method in Python does not actually replace the variable but instead creates a new string with the changes made. What you then have to do is assign this "new" string to a variable to store it or to my understanding you can assign the result to the original variable to overwrite it. Even after those steps however the .replace method still refuses to work.

Here's the code that I am having problem with :

```
url = input("Stream urls: ")
urls = url.split("," or "/" or " ")

# Find urls in the provided string
def find_url():
    findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', url)

# Format and clear urls
def format_url():
    for url in urls:
        if "https://www." in url:
            url = url.replace("https://www.", "https://")
        elif "www." in url:
            url = url.replace("www.", "https://")
        elif "http://" in url:
            url = url.replace("http://", "https://")
```

As seen in the code a user is asked to put in links which are then converted to a list with a possible separator of each link with ', / " "'. This part and the next part are provided only for goal reference and there doesn't seem to be any issue with them. The problematic part is te format_url() function.

At first I thought that the replace method logically cannot be used on lists so I made a for loop which loops throught every single link in the links list. This to my understanding should result in the .replace method only obtaining 1 record at a time which should make it work.

I also didn't forget to call the methods with :

```
find_url()
format_url()
url_source()
```

Comment: Well, for one, the boolean expression `"," or "/" or " "` will always evaluate to the first truthy string it comes across, due to short-circuiting, so you'll only split on `","`. If you want to split on multiple potential characters, try `re.split` from the `re` module. The issue you actually seem to be struggling with is the reassignment of `url` inside your for-loop. This will not work the way you intended, because `url` is just a copy of whatever the current string is, and any changes you apply to the copy will not be reflected in the original string in the list.

Comment: The fix would be to `enumerate` through your `urls` list, such that you get the current string as well as the index of the current string, and then apply your changes via `urls[i] = url.replace(...)`. Another solution would be to rebuild a new `urls` list with the applied changes with a list-comprehension or something similar.

Comment: I want to elaborate on what I said about "any changes you apply to the copy will not be reflected in the original string". To be precise, you aren't mutating the current string in any way, you're re-binding what string the `url` variable "points" at. Re-binding the copy will have no effect on the original string in the list from which it came.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the last comment. If I am "rebinding" the string with what the url variable points at shouldn't it always point to the exact url variable that currentyl runs inside of that for loop? I am currently working on a solution that counts with the list posioning so hopefully I get it set up.

Comment: The sequence of events is something like this: Create a distinct variable `url`, and have it point at the same string that `urls[0]` points at. Then, if one of the `if` or `elif`s are satisfied, re-bind `url`, and make it point to another string - namely, the result of `url.replace`. The original strings inside `urls` are completely unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's more helpful to post an answer, rather than just comments. Hopefully this should illustrate the issue:

```
strings = ["hello", "yellow", "jello"]

for current_string in strings:
    current_string = current_string.replace("e", "3")
    print(f"current_string is {current_string}, and strings is {strings}")
```

Output:

```
current_string is h3llo, and strings is ['hello', 'yellow', 'jello']
current_string is y3llow, and strings is ['hello', 'yellow', 'jello']
current_string is j3llo, and strings is ['hello', 'yellow', 'jello']
>>>
```

As you can see, `current_string` does not behave like a handle to each string in `strings`. It's just a copy. Mutating or re-binding the copy has no effect on the strings from which it was derived.

Here's one way you can apply the changes:

```
strings = ["hello", "yellow", "jello"]

for index, current_string in enumerate(strings):
    strings[index] = current_string.replace("e", "3")

print(strings)
```

Output:

```
['h3llo', 'y3llow', 'j3llo']
>>>
```

While we're at it, take a look at this:

```
>>> "," or "/" or " "
','
>>>
```

As mentioned in my previous comment, such a boolean expression (chained `or`s) will evaluate to the first truthy string it comes across due to short circuiting, from left to right. A string is considered "truthy" if it is not empty. So, the first non-empty string is `","`. Therefore, you only split on `","`.

Comment: That worked and I see where the issue was. I have actually never found a use for the enumarate parameter but now I finally see it's use in the real world. Thanks for helping me out!